# Django update_or_create() from JSON when key may or may not exist

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-views

So i am create a function where data is being pushed to models from the JSON file. There is a possibility that my JSON **may** or **may not** have the desired key. but i am not sure how can i **pass default value such as N/A if key not existed**.

**Sample JSON:** Here 1st object have **title** key and 2nd does not h

```
    {"timestamp":"2023-04-20T15:45:53.085646251+05:30","status_code":200,"content_length":17620,"failed":false, "title":Test Website}
    {"timestamp":"2023-04-20T15:45:53.085646251+05:30","status_code":200,"content_length":17620,"failed":false}
```

**Django view:**

```
    data = []
    for line in open(results.json', 'r'):
        data.append(json.loads(line))
        
    for item in data:
        obj, created = http.objects.update_or_create(asset=item['input'], defaults={
            'status_code':item['status_code'],
            'title':item['title'],
            'last_added':datetime.now()},)
```

This gives me **KeyError('title')**

***Can I add default value to be added only if key not existed?***

Answer (score 0):

you can define a function which will return the value if it exists and default value if doesn't

```
for item in data:
    obj, created = http.objects.update_or_create(asset=item['input'], defaults={
        'status_code': item['status_code'],
        'title': get_title(item),
        'last_added': datetime.now()},)

def get_title(item):
    return item.get('title', 'your default value')
```

`get_title()` returns the title it it's present or a default value otherwise